# How to check if network shared EXE file is used by more than one user?

Tags: windows, delphi, file, network-share

I have an application which sits on a server in the network shared folder. Many users in network, can use that file simultaneously. I would like to perform an update of that EXE file and to do this, I would like to know who in network (besides me) is currently using that file.

Is it possible to check this programmatically? For example: to list all user names who are using that file now? Or atleast to retrieve number of locks on that file?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want do this from the server side o from a client machine?

Comment: Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but SysInternal's [PsFile](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897552) can tell you who has open files on a certain machine. They mention using some NET API, which I'm not familiar with, but it might be a lead for you.

Comment: @RRUZ Ideally it would be a client application. I don't mind if client application must run some updater.exe process on the server.
@eran thanks, I will check it out.

Comment: @Wodzu I just published an article on my blog which can give you more details about the shared resources in local and remote machines http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/using-delphi-and-adsi-to-enumerate-local-and-remote-shared-resources/

Comment: @RRUZ Cool, I read it, nice job. However I bit more emphasise on calling convention would be good casue I had strange error because of this. I'll check how it works cause I have problems with connecting to server in my domain when using your older code. (Perhaps becuase I've ignored username and password).

Comment: @Wodzu I read your question about the memory issues when you uses the `ADsGetObject` and I can't reproduce the problem, anyway the calling convention (stdcall vs safecall) in this kind of functions only affects how Delphi handle the exceptions. about the `old code` posted in this answer , is only intended for local access, for a more flexible way check the method used in the blog post using the `ADsOpenObject` function.

Comment: @RRUZ Have you used exactly the same code as in my example? Anyway the reason was that in the example you gave me, you used a wrong calling convention which messed up the registers. Not that I am blaming you;) you've helped me very much and I've learn a lot from it:) I allow myself to post some questions on your blog in case I will have problems with connecting to the remote machine tommorow at work. Regards :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To list the open shared files in a machine you can use ADSI (Active Directory Service Interfaces).

In order to use these interfaces from delphi you must import the Active DS type library

[image]

Then access the [`IADsFileServiceOperations`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa706015%28VS.85%29.aspx) interface, which contains a method called [`Resources`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa706016%28VS.85%29.aspx)  this method return a collection with all the shared resources opened.

Check this sample code

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  ActiveDs_TLB,
  Variants,
  ActiveX,
  SysUtils;


function ADsGetObject(lpszPathName:WideString; const riid:TGUID; out ppObject):HRESULT; safecall; external 'activeds.dll';


procedure ListSharedResourcesInUse;
var
  FSO           : IADsFileServiceOperations;
  Resources     : IADsCollection;
  Resource      : OleVariant;
  pceltFetched  : Cardinal;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
begin
  //establish the connection to ADSI
  ADsGetObject('WinNT://./lanmanserver', IADsFileServiceOperations, FSO);
  //get the resources interface 
  Resources := FSO.Resources;
  //get the enumerator
  oEnum:= IUnknown(Resources._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while oEnum.Next(1, Resource, pceltFetched) = 0 do
  begin
    Writeln(Format('Resource %s User %s',[Resource.Path,Resource.User]));
    Resource:=Unassigned;
  end;
end;


begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      ListSharedResourcesInUse;
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;
end.
```

Comment: Thanks @RRUZ, unfortunately it does not work as expected. To be more specific, it works only once. If I chose some directory to share with users, I enable it and run your example it shows that directory. But then if I turn off your example and turn on it again, it shows nothing? Very strange..

Comment: Ok, now I get it, I need to connect to that resource through the network even if I am at my server \ host computer. Just out of the curiosity, have you hade previous experience with this or did you search Internet to help me with this?

Comment: Sure I've working with `ADSI` in the past, why your ask?. In fact I've work a lot with COM based technologies Like ADSI, WMI, Scripting and others.

Comment: I just wanted to know the way you obtained that info, cause I did a lot of searching yesterday without a succes. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Wodzu, The MSDN has a complete reference to `ADSI`, check these links http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772218%28VS.85%29.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772217%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: RRUZ, Care to take a look at related problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663985/strange-memory-overwrite-problem-in-instance-of-my-class

Answer (score 3):

If what you really need is to replace an exe file, that may be in use, you can rename the executable, and then just copy the new file on the same location. New users will run the new executable, where as the old (renamed) one can be deleted as soon as the last user, running it, closes the application.

Comment: I've used this approach successfully on several occasions. Nevertheless, I'm not sure if it is reliable.

Comment: @Silver thanks for the suggestion, but this is not acceptable for me. I need to update also the database, thus I need to know is someone is currently using the EXE or not.

Comment: @Wodzu How are you going to update the database and update the EXE in a single atomic transaction. A direct answer to your question, just addressing the EXE update is not going to make the entire update operation atomic.

Comment: @David I don't know if this is a good solution but if I know that specific EXE is not running than I know that my database is not used and I can update those two things, of course during the update something can happen. 
During the update I will leave a flag in database that it is updated and each client will check that flag on the start of application and it won't run if the DB is during update.

Answer (score 1):

It might be overkill, but what about having a server-client architecture? An app could be running on your server, and each time someone launches a client, it connects to the server.

Add a "status/state" to the equation which can change to your current need: NORMAL, PREPARING FOR UPGRADE, UPGRADE IN PROGRESS, etc

This way you could iterate through the list of opened connections and send a message to everyone that the system will be put in maintenance mode, or when the client gets launched it can notify the user of what's going on.

Cheers

Comment: I was thinking about simmilar solution. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Don't mention it, the more ideas the closer to finding an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you start exe it will be locked for write. So it is safe to replace or rename exe, but if you can not this mean that exe is used.

PsFile and "net file" can show if file is opened and you can close file. But this is not good for users that are started program.

I think it is best if you create function to send message to all users of program. If you need upgrade disable new logins and send message to all users "Please exit, upgrade is required!". Retry this until you can replace exe. PsFile can not tell who is using file but only if file is used.