# Strange memory overwrite problem in instance of my class

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, access-violation

This problem is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649567/how-to-check-if-network-shared-exe-file-is-used-by-more-than-one-user) question, which I've asked earlier. 
The code provided by @RRUZ is working but it seems that not quite correctly or
I am doing something wrong.

After executing `GetSharedFiles` strange thing is happening in instance of `TMyObject`. The field `FMyEvent` which was (and it should be) nil points to some random data.

What I've discovered just 5 minutes ago is that if I **turn off** the optimization in compiler options it works fine after rebuild. So maybe this is some compiler bug?

Here is a code snapshot (Delphi 2009 Windows 7 64 bit):

```
unit Unit17;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm17 = class(TForm)
    btnetst: TButton;
    procedure btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

type
  TMyEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject) of object;

type
  TMyObject = class(TObject)
  private
    FMyEvent: TMyEvent;
    function GetSharedFiles: TStringList;
  public
    property OnEvent: TMyEvent read FMyEvent write FMyEvent;
    procedure DoSomething;
  end;

var
  Form17: TForm17;

implementation

uses
  ActiveDs_TLB,
  ActiveX;

function ADsGetObject(lpszPathName:WideString; const riid:TGUID; out ppObject):HRESULT; safecall; external 'activeds.dll';

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm17.btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyObject: TMyObject;
begin
  MyObject := TMyObject.Create;
  try
    MyObject.DoSomething;
  finally
    if Assigned(MyObject) then
      MyObject.Free;
  end;
end;

{ TMyObject }

procedure TMyObject.DoSomething;
var
  TmpList: TStringList;
begin
  try

    TmpList := GetSharedFiles; //something is overwritting the memory in object and puts random data to FMyEvent?
    if Assigned(FMyEvent) then
      ShowMessage('WTF'); //this should not be called, and if you comment out GetSharedFiles it won't.

  finally
    if Assigned(TmpList) then
      TmpList.Free;
  end;
end;


function TMyObject.GetSharedFiles: TStringList;
var
  FSO           : IADsFileServiceOperations;
  Resources     : IADsCollection;
  Resource      : OleVariant;
  pceltFetched  : Cardinal;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
begin
  Result := TStringList.Create;
  //establish the connection to ADSI
  if ADsGetObject('WinNT://./lanmanserver', IADsFileServiceOperations, FSO) = S_OK then
  begin
    //get the resources interface
    Resources := FSO.Resources;
    //get the enumerator
    oEnum:= IUnknown(Resources._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
    while oEnum.Next(1, Resource, pceltFetched) = 0 do
    begin
      Result.Add(LowerCase(Format('%s%s%s',[Resource.Path,#9,Resource.User])));
      Resource:=Unassigned;
    end;
  end;
end;    
end.
```

Any ideas what is going wrong? 
Thanks for your time.

Comment: I do not believe this is a compiler bug. It's much more likely that you are writing over some memory bounds, and Delphi adds extra padding in Debug mode, therefore preventing you from overwriting FMyEvent.

Comment: Ok, but I am using only this code, nothing more.

Comment: Have you tried with the *exact* same code as provided to you by RRUZ? (esp. getting rid of the TStringList/LowerCase(Format(... in your code)?

Comment: If I remove Result.Add() and leave only LowerCase(Format('%s%s%s',[Resource.Path,#9,Resource.User])) it works.

Comment: "If I remove Result.Add() and leave only..." - - - Probably you are just changing the conditions that trigger the bug to manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calling convention on this should probably be `stdcall`, not `safecall`:

```
function ADsGetObject(lpszPathName:WideString; const riid:TGUID; out ppObject):HRESULT; safecall; external 'activeds.dll';
```

---

#### Recap

Typical COM functions return a `HRESULT` result; They use it to pass an error code or `S_OK` if everything went fine. Using this type of function, you'd usually have this kind of code:

```
if CallComFunction(parameters) = S_OK then
  begin
    // Normal processing goes here
  end
else
  begin
    // Error condition needs to be dealt with here.
  end
```

Since error conditions can't usually be dealt with, Delphi provides us with the `safecall` pseudo-calling-convention. It's not a true calling convention because in fact it uses `stdcall` behind the scenes. What it does is to automatically generate the test for `S_OK` and, on failure, raises an error. So the typical COM method can be declared as either one of this:

```
function TypicalComFunction(Parameters): HRESULT; stdcall;
procedure TypicalComFunction(Parameters); safecall;
```

If you don't intend to deal with any potential errors use the second form (with `safecall`) and simply ignore the potential exception. If an error does occur, Delphi will raise an Exception, and that exception will bubble-up until it reaches a point in the application that *can* deal with the error. Or it bubbles up until it reaches Application's exception handler, and that's used to display the error for the user.

Using `safecall`, the typical code above looks like this:

```
TypicalComFunction(Parameters); // raises exception on error    
// Normal processing goes here
```

On the other hand if you *do* need the `HRESUL` even if it's different from `S_OK`, then use the `stdcall` variant.

Comment: Cosmin, it works when I change the calling convention but I don't understand why. It should be a safecall when COM methods are used, right?

Comment: if you are going to use safecall, and I think you should, then you need to get rid of the function return value.

Comment: @David, why use `safecall`? I admit I don't have much experience with COM. But on my last encounter, when working with IMAPI2 for DVD authoring, I had to replace same of the Delphi-imported `safecall` procedures to `stdcall` functions returning HRESULT, because `safecall` masked the result codes the functions returned. Because of that I'd rather use `stdcall`.

Comment: So it should look like this: procedure ADsGetObject(lpszPathName:WideString; const riid:TGUID; out ppObject); safecall; external 'activeds.dll'; and then HResult will be returned as an exception in case of error. If I understand it correctly.

Comment: @Cosmin i think it is like this by design: quote from wiki: In Borland Delphi on Microsoft Windows, the safecall calling convention encapsulates COM (Component Object Model) error handling, so that exceptions aren't leaked out to the caller, but are reported in the HRESULT return value, as required by COM/OLE. When calling a safecall function from Delphi code, Delphi also automatically checks the returned HRESULT and raises an exception if necessary.

Comment: `safecall` is used to automatically convert `HRESULT`s to COM exceptions. If the function returns a `HRESULT` it should probably be `stdcall`, not `safecall`.

Comment: @Wodzu, who's design is that, and why should we follow it? When you use `safecall` you no longer get direct access to `HRESULT`. As I mentioned before, when working with IMAPI2, I had to revert `safecall` to `stdcall` because I *needed* the actual HRESULT to show meaningful error messages, lile "Hey, you forgot to put the disk into the drive". Catching exceptions in order to figure out the error codes doesn't seem like good design to me.

Comment: @Cosmin I don't know who implemented that, just read this article on wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#safecall As far as i understand you can have an error as function result or as an exception. I admit that having error as result is more convenient.

Comment: I don't understand what's this got to do anything with COM, it's a regular function exported from Activeds.dll.

Comment: @Cosmin If you want `HRESULT`s turned into exceptions then you would use `safecall`. I prefer not to catch exceptions and not to handle errors where tenable.

Comment: I am totally at a loss now, what are *"typical COM functions"*? This function does not operate on a COM object, what makes a function not involved in COM a COM function?

Comment: `safecall` is associated with HRESULT errors and not tied to COM.

Answer (score 0):

No, this does not mean a compiler bug per se. Changing compiler (Delphi<->FPC), compiler version or optimization options can affect codegeneration, and optimize away reference counted temps or free them earlier, or alter used registers and register allocation.

This in turn can make real hidden bugs pop up and off.

An example of such problem is that you call external functions. If for some reason their prototype (declaration in the relevant unit) is wrong, registers can get mutilated, and again varying of compiler options can cause heisenbug behaviour.

Also refcounting problems with automated types, or modifying global variables that are passed via CONST somewhere can cause such problems. There is a huge thread about the latter problem on the main FPC maillist atm.

**Remember**: code that has been working for a long time is not necessarily correct.

Comment: you are probably right with the external functions call, I did as @Cosmin Prund suggested and it started working. I understand that calling convention has impact on the registers, but this is COM method and as far as I know it should be called with safecall convention?

Comment: Well, it exactly matches the prototype in header mismatch that I mentioned. Registers only change if the function has a return value, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#safecall

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to be a compiler bug. Set a data breakpoint on the field and you'll find the code that is overwriting the field.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar bug in the past. It appeared ONLY when the compiler optimization was on. Otherwise, the code worked for about 2 years without problems. This is because the code compiled with optimization ON is very different than the code compiled with optimization OFF!!!!!!! The bug can manifest (or not) because of these chances.

Hints:

- Use FastMM (set on aggressive debugging mode)
- ALWAYS use FreeAndNil instead of Free. This may help you A LOT since it may force the bug in your code to appear sooner - maybe also in the code compiled with optimizations off. This will actually demonstrate that the bug was there all the time. You can do a massive 'search and replace' in your code for '.Free'.

These two tricks helped me to find the bug.

Comment: thank you for your input. I am now quite sure that my error was caused by incorrect marking(fastcall /stdcall) of external function.